# Behavior of '-e' option during emacs invocation

Tags: invocation

There command-line option `-e` behaves *similar* to the `--eval` option, but yet it is not the same.  For example, of these two invocations, only the first one works:

```
emacs --eval '(global-linum-mode)'
emacs     -e '(global-linum-mode)'
```

And of these two invocations, only the second one works:

```
emacs --eval 'global-linum-mode'
emacs     -e 'global-linum-mode'
```

I had mistakenly assumed that `-e` was the "short form" for `--eval` based on this line from the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Invocation.html#Emacs-Invocation):

> There are two ways of writing options: the short forms that start with
>   a single ‘-’, and the long forms that start with ‘--’. For example,
>   ‘-d’ is a short form and ‘--display’ is the corresponding long form.

But as I noted, it has a behavior which differs from the long option. Is this mysterious `-e` option documented anywhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a synonym for `-f` / `--funcall`, included for backwards compatibility.

The argument-handling code in `command-line-1` says:

```
"-f"    ; what the manual claims
"-funcall"
"-e"))  ; what the source used to say
```

Comment: So backward compatibility with a *mistake* in the old sources won out over [doing what the manual says](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Invocation.html)?  If they are going to keep this legacy cruft around, they should at least document it. `M-x report-emacs-bug`, here I come. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Perhaps more useful than documentation of a deprecated option would be if Emacs generated a *warning* if `-e` is used, so that people have notice to make the change; then it could be safely removed in some subsequent release.